# Using database.yml in rake tasks instead of providing user/pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I convert (this works):

```
desc "Import Bar"
task :import_bar => :environment do
  OCI8.new('user', 'pass', 'database').exec('select foo from bar') do |r| 
    puts r
  end
end
```

To something like this (not working):

```
desc "Import Bar"
task :import_bar => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select foo from bar') do |r|
    puts r
  end
end
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: database
  username: user
  password: pass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

`rake import_bar`

no output

Comment: Have you tried `puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select foo from bar')`?

Comment: good idea. here is the output: `#<OCI8::Cursor:0x000001039b8fd0>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to iterate through the objects using fetch, try:

```
desc "Import Bar"
task :import_bar => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select foo from bar').fetch() do |r|
    r.join(',')
  end
end
```

Comment: That's pretty weird, as for example with Mysql adapter you are supposed to receive Mysql2::Result for ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT * FROM entries') which is supposed to receive each. Can you print out ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select foo from bar').class

Comment: Please try iterate through cursor object you got, something like: 
while r = cursor.fetch()
  puts r.join(',')
end

Comment: of course cursor is the object you got with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select foo from bar')

Comment: @Bruno I just updated the answer, please check it out and let me know if it's working fine

Comment: Done, please accept the answer if it's working for you.